# How to replace all characters of a String while using a variable?

Tags: swift

I wanted to know how I could replace each of the characters in my variable randWords with "?", depending on the size of the word. I posted my code below but there is an error. For example, "House" would be "?????" and "Cat" would be "???"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var words = [String]()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    
       if let gameFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "hangmanWords", withExtension: "txt"){
           if let gameContents = try? String(contentsOf: gameFileURL){
               words = gameContents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
           }
       }
       loadGame()
   }

   func loadGame() {
       let randWord = words.randomElement()
       let newWord = String(repeating: "?", count:randword.count)
       title = newWord
   }

}
```

Comment: You mentioned there's an error but you didn't say which error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

1. `randword.count` have spelling mistakes. it's `randWord.count`
2. `randomElement()`, It gives you optional value so add default value.

```
let randWord = words.randomElement() ?? ""
```